# Scaling in Gimp 2.9 causes scaled object to whiten

Tags: gimp, scaling

Whenever I scale something up or down using Gimp 2.9, it causes the scaled object to whiten.
Example:

Original:

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102020907/Original.jpg]

Scaled:

[image]

Is this a bug with Gimp 2.9, or a setting I have to change?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disabling Hardware Acceleration (OpenCL) and restarting Gimp.

Comment: You could report this as a bug then.